# How do I create a custom utility type that adds a field to any given object type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to modify an Interface (or Type) to include an extra field in certain cases, the implementation I saw looked like:

```
interface Person {
  name: string
}
const person: WithAge<Person> = {name: "Foo", age: 123 }
```

How can I recreate this?

Comment: Did you look at how WithAge was implemented?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it was a large library and I was dreading cracking it open and stumbling around trying to understand it

Comment: Your IDE can probably take you to that one exact type, it's quicker than posting on SO!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using an intersection type:

```
type WithAge<T> = T & {age: number}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for your help kaya3!